# HTML 5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want some interaction on my game. Currently, I can drag them over the recycle bin and then they stay there. I would like them to disappear and leave a message that says, Yes, you are correct or good recycling. How do I do this? I'm just learning javascript, so I need simple.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

        body {

        }
        #div1 {
    width:478px;
    height:331px;
    padding:10px;
    background-image:url(../Images/recycle_bin.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:auto; 
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    }

        *[draggable=true] {
          -moz-user-select:none;
          -khtml-user-drag: element;
          cursor: move;
        }

        .instructions {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:19px;
    color:#255e02;  
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:12px;
        }



</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
ev.preventDefault();
}


</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="instructions">
<p>This is Ms. Mumford's Recycle Game. You will learn about recycling. Some items on this page cannot be recycled. Others can. </p>
<p>Drag the things that you can recycle to the recycle bin.</p>
</div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div>
<img id="drag1" src="../Images/Mountaindew.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
<img id="drag2" src="../Images/snapple.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
<img id="drag3" src="../Images/newspaper.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
//using jQuery to empty the div, or document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=""
$("#div1").empty();
//alert, or add your own popup
alert("Yes, you are correct or good recycling.");
```

at the end of `drop()`, like this:

```
function drop(ev){
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    ev.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="";
    alert("Yes, you are correct or good recycling.");
}
```

LIVE Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Nb3An/
(fullscreen) http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Nb3An/show